# libgdx - Actor input events not firing

Tags: java, android, game-engine, libgdx

Im testing libgdx but I'm getting stuck in user input handling.

My first attempt was using Gdx.input directly from render method but I feel like reinventing the wheel cause I'm writing a lot of code to detect the input area when I get touch events.

I'm almost sure a better way should be using Actor class but there's something I must be doing wrong becase the events never fire.

Here's my code:

```
...
    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("assets/sprite-sheet.png"));
            singlePlayerButton = new Image("SinglePlayerButton", new TextureRegion(texture,0,0,50,50)){

                @Override
                public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("touch down");
                    return super.touchDown(x, y, pointer);
                }

                @Override
                public void touchUp(float x, float y, int pointer) {
                    System.out.println("touch up");             
                }

            };

            stage.addActor(singlePlayerButton);
...

public void render(float delta) {
        // Clear the screen
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);           
        stage.draw();
        spriteBatch.end();
    }
```

The image displays well but it doesn't matter how many times I click on it I never get the event fired. What am i missing? Register the event? I can't find any addTouchListener() method in Stage or Actor class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to register all input processors with libGDX. Stage implements `InputProcessor`, so you have to register it:

```
@Override
public void create() {
    //... initialization

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it was a silly question but this game engine stills lack from a good documentation (This is not a critic against the engine, to be honest I consider it an awesome project). Can I at any time override this input procesor with a different stage?

Comment: You can use InputMultiplexer for this. You can add/remove InputProcessors to multiplexer as you need. Or just set another InputProcessor when you need.